# "cannot parse Procfile" error when Heroku uploading

Tags: heroku, hosting, push, procfile, heroku-api

Pic of the files in the github repo:

[image: error preview]

When I try uploading I get the error:

> Push failed: cannot parse Procfile. Please try pushing again.

Anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: please add the content inside your `Procfile` and requirements.txt file

Comment: Can you please share your Procfile